# How to extract and re-import NTFS metadata?

Tags: windows, metadata, file-transfer, ntfs

I have a bunch of files on my HDD which contains metadata information that I use to sort huge collections of files(Information such as Year/Artist/Rating/Comments and whatnots)

I would like to be able to transfer this information from one system to another;However, whenever the files are compressed and/or converted, all the metadata is deleted.

So I thought that maybe there would be some kind of software that would allow me to parse the metadata to a file and then allow me to import it back to my files once they have been transferred?

Personally, I prefer CLU/Batch/Command line kind of software(or a python library?) so I can program the tool to my preferences, but a GUI software would be fine too.

The file types could be anything, from .pdf to .djvu, .mp3 to .tak, .jpg to .webp .. (I believe the metadata is NOT within the file itself, or else how could I right click a file and see properties?)
Note: I am on a Windows 7 Operating system

Comment: _"I believe the metadata is NOT within the file itself, or else how could I right click a file and see properties?"_  - that's a non sequitur. Windows can parse EXIF, ID3, PE and other metadata directly from the file's contents. Or, differently, what would you think prevents Windows Explorer from reading metadata directly from a file when right-clicking it?

Comment: Are you simply trying to figure out file type?

Comment: I use the metadata for archiving purposes. If I need to detect a file type I use another application(TrId and Jhove). Reasons why I said that I think the metadata isn't saved within the file is because I'm not quite sure how "alien" file types can handle Exif/ID3 and things like that.

Comment: Also there is a file type .wmf which stands for windows metadata file. This file appears to be used for bitmaps nd vector graphics for images, though can be erroneously used to execute code. This also makes your question confusing, as it appears what you are trying to do contains abstract metadata contained in various file types, conforming to some kind of encoding standard I presume. Can you specify this?

Comment: Okay sorry, this is normally internal files used by windows operating system. You would either require special drivers or tools provided by windows for dealing with these as far as I can tell.

Comment: Or maybe uefi/bios script for NTFS meta file try searching.

Comment: I think I may have found what I need by searching for that; A GitHub post named "FileMeta". Thanks for the search suggestion, I will check that project out and tell the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the FileMeta project( Found here https://github.com/Dijji/FileMeta ) has a context menu and a command line utility for saving the metadata(and importing it back).
It seems that what I was actually needing to copy are the files "alternate data stream"

With a little more searching for that term, I found out that the Winrar archiver is able to copy this stream while compressing a file within a .rar file, By using its cmd utility with the -os switch or by toggling "saving file streams" in the advanced section while creating an archive.

7z is also able to perform this, but only with .wim files(however I think rar files are more beneficial for their compression ratio)

If anyone has some other methods, please share.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use WIM (windows image) files to capture both the files and the metadata. WIM files are specifically designed for storing files from NTFS filesystems, including all possible metadata.

This can be done either:

- With window's built-in [`DISM /Capture-Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14?view=windows-11#capture-image) and [`DISM /Apply-Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14?view=windows-11#apply-image).

  Capture: (create archive)

  ```
  DISM.exe /Capture-Image /ImageFile:X:\MyMusicArchive.wim /CaptureDir:C:\MySweetMusic /Name:Music
  ```

  Apply: (extract archive)

  ```
  DISM.exe /Apply-Image /ImageFile:X:\MyMusicArchive.wim /ApplyDir:C:\MySweetMusicFromArchive
  ```
- With [wimlib](https://wimlib.net/)'s [capture](https://wimlib.net/man1/wimcapture.html) and [apply](https://wimlib.net/man1/wimapply.html) commands:

  Capture: (create archive)

  ```
  wimcapture.exe C:\MySweetMusic X:\MyMusicArchive.wim
  ```

  Apply: (extract archive)

  ```
  wimapply.exe X:\MyMusicArchive.wim C:\MySweetMusicFromArchive
  ```